# Make grouping HTML element at the same line vertical in the footer

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

Hello hope you are doing well!
I am creating a footer I am sharing my code through the link:

```css
*{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

html{
    font-size: 10px;
    font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
}

body{
    width: 100%;
}
p{
    font-size: 1.6rem;
    line-height: 1.3;
    color: #333;
    font-weight: 400;
}
section{
    padding: 70px 0;
}

.container{
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0 2.5rem;
    margin: 0 auto;
    max-width: 120rem;
}


/* FOOTER */
/* FOOTER */
/* FOOTER */

footer {
    background-color: #f2f2f2;
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #666;
    padding: 50px 0;
  }
  

  .footer{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;

  }

  .footer-contacts{
    display: flex;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
  }

  .footer-phone,.footer-email{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    margin-right: 20px;
  }

  .footer-phone a,.footer-email a{
   text-decoration: none;
   margin-left: 5px;
  }


  .footer-columns {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-evenly;
    align-items: center;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
  }
 
 
  .footer-column h3 {
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
  }
  
  ul li {
    list-style: none;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
  }
```

```html
 <footer>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="footer">
                <div class="footer-contacts">
                    <div class="footer-phone">
                        <img src="https://i.postimg.cc/nL1LD5tD/contact-phone.png" alt="contact-phone" width="30px" height="auto">
                        <a href="tel:+49(0) 123 456 78 000">+49(0) 123 456 78 000</a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="footer-email">
                        <img src="https://i.postimg.cc/nL1LD5tD/contact-phone.png" alt="contact-email" width="30px" height="auto">
                        <a href="mailto:webmaster@example.com">webmaster@example.com</a>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>
            <div class="footer-columns">
                <div class="footer-column">
                    <h3>Vivamus</h3>
                    <ul>
                        <li>Product 1</li>
                        <li>Product 2</li>
                        <li>Product 3</li>
                        <li>Product 4</li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="footer-column">
                    <h3>Elementum</h3>
                    <ul>
                        <li>Product 1</li>
                        <li>Product 2</li>
                        <li>Product 3</li>
                        <li>Product 4</li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="footer-column">
                    <ul>
                        <li>Product 1</li>
                        <li>Product 2</li>

                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>

         

        </div>

    </footer>
```

[image]
I want that first grouping HTML element that contain image phone number and phone number to be at the same line with first column. Also is the same thing for secondly grouping HTML element that contain image email and text email to be at the same line with secondly column. Like image above.

I want that first grouping HTML Element to be at the same line with first column also is the same for secondly grouping html element and secondly column  to be at the same line I try to give margin-right grouping html element but destroy  layout. Any idea that can help me.?

Answer (score 0):

You can use grid instead of flexbox. Then you can just make all the columns the same width, and put what you want lined up in the same column.

```css
*{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

html{
    font-size: 10px;
    font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
}

body{
    width: 100%;
}
p{
    font-size: 1.6rem;
    line-height: 1.3;
    color: #333;
    font-weight: 400;
}
section{
    padding: 70px 0;
}

.container{
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0 2.5rem;
    margin: 0 auto;
    max-width: 120rem;
}


/* FOOTER */
/* FOOTER */
/* FOOTER */

footer {
    background-color: #f2f2f2;
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #666;
    padding: 50px 0;
  }
  

  .footer{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;

  }

  .footer-phone,.footer-email{
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
  }

  .footer-phone a,.footer-email a{
   text-decoration: none;
   margin-left: 5px;
  }

.footer-contacts,
.footer-columns {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
}
 
@media (width < 700px) {
  .footer-contacts {
    grid-template-columns: 1fr;
    gap: 1em;
  }
  .footer-phone,
  .footer-email {
    justify-content: center;
  }
}

@media (width < 350px) {
  .footer-columns {
    grid-template-columns: 1fr;
    gap: 1em;
  }
}
  .footer-column h3 {
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
  }
  
  ul li {
    list-style: none;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
  ｝
```

```html
<footer>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="footer">
            <div class="footer-contacts">
                   <div class="footer-phone">
                       <img src="https://i.postimg.cc/nL1LD5tD/contact-phone.png" alt="contact-phone" width="30px" height="auto">
                       <a href="tel:+49(0) 123 456 78 000">+49(0) 123 456 78 000</a>
                   </div>
                   <div class="footer-email">
                      <img src="https://i.postimg.cc/nL1LD5tD/contact-phone.png" alt="contact-email" width="30px" height="auto">
                      <a href="mailto:webmaster@example.com">webmaster@example.com</a>
                   </div>
               </div>
        </div>
        <div class="footer-columns">
          <div class="footer-column">
                   <h3>Vivamus</h3>
                   <ul>
                       <li>Product 1</li>
                       <li>Product 2</li>
                       <li>Product 3</li>
                       <li>Product 4</li>
                   </ul>
               </div>
          <div class="footer-column">
                   <h3>Elementum</h3>
                   <ul>
                       <li>Product 1</li>
                       <li>Product 2</li>
                       <li>Product 3</li>
                       <li>Product 4</li>
                   </ul>
               </div>
          <div class="footer-column">
                   <ul>
                       <li>Product 1</li>
                       <li>Product 2</li>
                   </ul>
               </div>
        </div>
    </div>         
</footer>
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, this solution works well for desktop but doesn't make responsive in mobile device.

Comment: @Mery I have updated my answer to use grid instead of flexbox.